# What php configuration variable disallows concatenated array indexes?

Tags: php, php-ini

E.G.

```
if(!isset($am_states[$lot.'_-40C'])){
```

or

```
$am_states[$temp."_".$states[$i]['temperature']] = $states[$i]['temperature'];
```

Whenever I have arrays with concatenated string as array-keys php returns an error:

**Parse error:** syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ']'

So I am assuming something is wrong with the server configuration although I am sure i changed something on my local configuration.
Last time i changed the configuration was when i setup my apache/mysql/php installation

that is PHP Version 5.3.1,Apache/2.2.14,MYSQL5.1.41 (default from xampp1.7.3)

so I was using this syntaxes 7 months ago and they were working properly. It just now that they produce errors.
Anyone can help?

Comment: I don't think this is something you can turn off, that's core PHP syntax and functionality. What PHP version are you running this on, and can you give any more information?

Comment: I also don't think this is a config var. Why not build a concatenated string for the index and reference the array with the string?

Comment: hmmm i didnt update my php version and it was working before...
phpinfo says its PHP Version 5.3.1

Comment: These work:

    `$a = array("foo"=>1); 
    $o = "o"; 
    echo $a["fo$o"] . $a["fo" . $o]; /* 11 */

    $a = array("0f00"=>1); 
    $o = "0"; 
    echo $a["$o"."f0$o"] . $a[$o."f0".$o]; /* 11 */
    
    // this won't --> $a["$of0$o"]; It is guessing that $oF0 is a variable name.`

So, the problem is probably somewhere else.

Comment: That code cannot throw such error.

Comment: @zerkms i know it shouldn't too

Comment: @lock: well - give us self-sufficient code that we can run and see that issue?

Comment: @lock: Grab the code from the place the error message specifies. The only way I can think of to get this error would be something like `$array['blah' . ]` (and, I'm not sure that would actually produce this error)

Comment: @Mike Caron: it is easy to try ;-) On 5.2.14 and 5.3.6 it produces `syntax error, unexpected ']'`. Not the same error. Anyway, cannot think of any code that could generate exactly that error message.

Comment: @zerkms: It is easy to try, when on a box with PHP installed, which I am not ;)

Comment: @Zerkms: When I invent my time machine, I'll let myself know about that ;)

Comment: @zerkms let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1311/discussion-between-mike-caron-and-zerkms)

Comment: I have had an issue with this in the past...don't know if it's the config or not, but having single quotes in the array key was the problem.  To clean things up, I always concat things in a variable then reference the variable in the array key...

Comment: @espradley: that'd be troublesome to use on an if-statement though, but its what I did anyway
i didnt see any explicit instruction from PHP to do something like this before which kind of makes it non-compliant to its loosely-typed structure

Comment: Yep, might be related to your PHP version, cause the code you wrote above works on 5.3...

Answer (score 0):

Are you positive about the PHP version you're using? The following test (using PHP 5.3.6 (cli)) works without issue. Perhaps you could post a more complete example?

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

$states = array(
    array('temperature' => 40),
    array('temperature' => 50),
    array('temperature' => 60)
);

$temp = 'test';
$i = 2;

$am_states[$temp . "_" . $states[$i]['temperature']] = $states[$i]['temperature'];

var_dump($am_states);
```

The output of this script is:

```
array(1) {
  ["test_60"]=>
  int(60)
}
```